# How to use around_action for all controllers except a specific one with some actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application controller i use around_action to set the time zone in every controller action :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     around_action :user_time_zone

     def user_time_zone(&block)
        Time.use_zone("Central America", &block)
     end
end
```

but in a specific controller i won't to apply this time zone with some actions, so i want something like this :

```
around_action :user_time_zone, except: {controller: "foo" & action: "bar" & action: "other_action"}
```

there is a way to this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In specific controller where you do not need this filter just skip it using 'skip_around_filter'

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  skip_around_filter :user_time_zone, :only => [:bar]

end
```

Note: skip_around_filter is supported in Rails 3.2.1 or higher version